# Change a csv file to shopify format

Tags: python, pandas, csv, shopify, swap

I am an absolute beginner when it comes to coding. I have the problem that I get a CSV file from my supplier that is not Shopify compliant. Now I have to change it so that I can upload it. I know how to change headers. The biggest problem is the image links. These are in multiple columns in the original file, but Shopify wants them in a column below each other. On a small scale, the supplier's CSV is structured like this:

{'Handle': 'abc', 'SKU': '123', 'Image-1': 'image-link', 'Image-2': 'image-link-2', 'Image-3': 'image-link-3', 'Image-4': 'image-link-4'}

[image]

and should be like this:

{'Handle': 'product-handle', 'Title': 'product-title', 'SKU': '12345', 'Image Src': 'image-link', 'Image Position': '1'}
{'Handle': 'product-handle', 'Title': '', 'SKU': '', 'Image Src': 'image-link-2', 'Image Position': '2'}
{'Handle': 'product-handle', 'Title': '', 'SKU': '', 'Image Src': 'image-link-3', 'Image Position': '3'}
{'Handle': 'product-handle', 'Title': '', 'SKU': '', 'Image Src': 'image-link-4', 'Image Position': '4'}

[image]

So i have to somehow swap some columns and rows, number them consecutively and copy the handle to each row.

Unfortunately, I have absolutely no clue how to do this, does anyone have an idea?